# ReadTimeOut Error while writer.write(xlist) in Alibaba odps connection. Any Suggestion?

Tags: python-3.x, data-migration, alibaba-cloud

```
from odps import ODPS
from odps import options
import csv
import os
from datetime import timedelta, datetime 

options.sql.use_odps2_extension = True
options.tunnel.use_instance_tunnel = True
options.connect_timeout = 60
options.read_timeout=130
options.retry_times = 7
options.chunk_size = 8192*2

odps = ODPS('id','secret','project', endpoint ='endpointUrl')
table = odps.get_table('eventTable')

def uploadFile(file):
    with table.open_writer(partition=None) as writer:
        with open(file, 'rt') as csvfile:
                rows = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='~')
                for final in rows:
                    writer.write(final)
    writer.close();

uploadFile('xyz.csv')
```

Assume I pass number of files in uploadFile call one by one from directory To connect alibaba cloud from python to migrate data into max compute table over the cloud. When I run this code, service stops either after  working long time or at night time. It reports me error Read Time Out Error at line writer.write(final).

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 226, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 301, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 448, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 488, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 660, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 344, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 311, in read
    flush_decoder = True
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 231, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='dt.odps.aliyun.com', port=80): Read timed out.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dataUploader.py", line 66, in <module>
    uploadFile('xyz.csv')       
  File "/dataUploader.py", line 53, in uploadFile
    writer.write(final)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odps/models/table.py", line 643, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odps/models/table.py", line 631, in close
    upload_session.commit(written_blocks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odps/tunnel/tabletunnel.py", line 308, in commit
    in self.get_block_list()])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odps/tunnel/tabletunnel.py", line 298, in get_block_list
    self.reload()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odps/tunnel/tabletunnel.py", line 238, in reload
    resp = self._client.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odps/rest.py", line 138, in get
    return self.request(url, 'get', stream=stream, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/odps/rest.py", line 125, in request
    proxies=self._proxy)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 608, in send
    r.content
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 737, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 667, in generate
    raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='dt.odps.aliyun.com', port=80): Read timed out.

packet_write_wait: Connection to 122.121.122.121 port 22: Broken pipe
```

This is the error what I got. Can you suggest what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The read timeout is the timeout on waiting to read data. Usually, if the server fails to send a byte  seconds after the last byte, a read timeout error will be raised.

This happens because of the server couldn`t read the file within the specified timeout period.

Here, the read timeout was set to 130 seconds, which is less if your file size is very high.

Please increase the timeout limit from 130 seconds to 500 seconds, i.e  `options.read_timeout=130` to `options.read_timeout=500`

It would resolve your problem, at the same time minimize the retry times from 7 to 3,
i.e `options.retry_times=7` to `options.retry_times=3`

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by network issue.

Execute `curl endpoint URL` in a terminal. If it returns immediately with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchObject</Code>
    <Message><![CDATA[Unknown http request location: /]]></Message>
    <RequestId>5E5CC9526283FEC94F19DAAE</RequestId>
    <HostId>localhost</HostId>
</Error>
```

Then the endpoint URL is reachable. But if it hangs, then you should check if you are using the right endpoint URL.

Since MaxCompute (ODPS) has public and private endpoint, it could be confusing sometimes.